# Get PlaceId using latitude and longitude in AGM

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am trying to get the placeId, lat and lng using AGM but 'mapClicked' function is returning undefined placeId, while using 'onMapReady' it returns an object with no placeId

google-maps.component.html

```
  <agm-map
      [latitude]="lat"
      [longitude]="lng"
      [zoom]="zoom"
      [disableDefaultUI]="false"
      [zoomControl]="false"
      (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">

      <agm-marker
        *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
        (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
        [latitude]="m.lat"
        [longitude]="m.lng"
        [label]="m.label"
        [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"
        (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">

        <agm-info-window>
          <strong>InfoWindow content</strong>
        </agm-info-window>

      </agm-marker>

      <agm-circle [latitude]="lat + 0.3" [longitude]="lng"
                  [radius]="5000"
                  [fillColor]="'red'"
                  [circleDraggable]="true"
                  [editable]="true">
      </agm-circle>

    </agm-map>
```

google-maps.component.ts

Below are the functions :

```
  mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
this.markers.push({
  lat: $event.coords.lat,
  lng: $event.coords.lng,
  draggable: true,
  placeId: $event.placeId // result : undefined
});}



onMapReady(map) {
map.addListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.results);
  console.log(e);
});}
```

Comment: no updates regarding this issue ?